# Gas fireplace won’t stay lit unless I remove glass

Tags: gas, fireplace

Runs good when I remove glass and lean it against opening otherwise it goes out
It’s a napoleon insert

Comment: It is not getting enough air to burn.  The flames should be blue with maybe a tiny yellow tip.  There should be an outside air inlet/pipe to provide combustion air.  It is blocked or missing completely.

Comment: And it would be a carbon-monoxide hazard if not repaired!